# disable sort in react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

```
let {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    state: { pageIndex, sortBy }
  } = useTable(
    {
      columns,
      data,
      sortable: {dsiabledSort}
      manualPagination: true,
      manualSortBy: true
    },
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
  );
```

dsiabledSort is variable it will be either false or true, its set to true, but still table have sorting...
I also tried simply

```
sortable:false
```

But still not working

Any help
Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`useSortBy` hook](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/blob/master/docs/api/useSortBy.md) with the `disableSortBy` option:

```
let {
    getTableProps,
    getTableBodyProps,
    headerGroups,
    prepareRow,
    page,
    canPreviousPage,
    canNextPage,
    nextPage,
    previousPage,
    state: { pageIndex, sortBy }
} = useTable(
    {
       columns,
       data,
       manualPagination: true,
       manualSortBy: true,
       disableSortBy: disabledSort // Add disableSortBy here
    },
    useSortBy,
    usePagination
);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for the doc link, but somehow I could not manage to find the link, I have just started react.js.. Thanks your answer worked, also for the doc link, which I usually prefer before asking to anyone

Answer (score 22):

On **Version 7** if you want to disable sort on a single column use `disableSortBy` on [columns definition](https://react-table-v7.tanstack.com/docs/api/useSortBy#column-options), for example:

```
{
    Header: 'Column Title',
    accessor: 'title',
    disableSortBy: true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Typescript version:

```
const MyColumns: (Column<IMyRow> & UseSortByColumnOptions<IMyRow>)[] = useMemo(() => [
    {
      Header: 'Date',
      accessor: 'date',
      disableSortBy: true,
    }
], [])
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me for react-table version ^7.7.0

```
 {
    header: () => <span>#</span>,
    accessorKey: "serialNo",
    enableSorting: false,
    cell: (row) => {
      return <div>{row?.row?.index + 1}</div>;
    },
  },
```

Just add a enableSorting key in columns and toggle it according to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check again to make sure no wrong typing such as `sortble` instead of `sortable: false`?

And I have noticed that in your code `sortable: {dsiabledSort}` should be replace by `sortable: disabledSort` (without curly braces).